# Check if component have attribute selector in angular2

Tags: angular

I wanna check if component has an attribute or not in Angular2. here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'field-group, field-group[half]',
    template: `
    <div class="field-group">
      <label *ngIf="label != ''">{{label}}</label>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <span class="validation" *ngIf="errorObject != ''"></span>
    </div>
    `
})
export class FieldGroupComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() label: string = '';
    @Input() errorObject: any;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

}
```

For the selector I added `[half]`. now how can I check this component have this selector in code when I used? where can I check this exist or not? and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to input:

```
selector: '[field-group]'
```

and then

```
@Input('field-group') fieldGroup: string;
```

Instantiation becomes:

```
<div [field-group]='half'>...</div>
```

or
    ...

then in your code (for example in `ngInit`):

```
if(fieldGroup === 'half'){...
```

Answer (score 3):

The recommended solution would be to read the attribute's value using `@Input` but does not guarantee attribute's existence vs empty attribute. Refer the demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/wYuiRS8gYcyiYZt79yko?p=preview

Non-recommended but suitable solution for you is to get the hold of the component element to check the attribute's existence using `ElementRef`.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'field-group, field-group[half]',
    template: `
    <div class="field-group">
      <label *ngIf="label != ''">{{label}}</label>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <span class="validation" *ngIf="errorObject != ''"></span>
    </div>
    `
})
export class FieldGroupComponent implements OnInit {
    label: string = '';
    errorObject: any;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('half'));
    }

}
```